# c++ program to extract the eyes,nose features of detected face using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on face recognition project for security purposes.First step is to detect the faces in still image.I have detected the faces but not able to save them.

Comment: Your going to need to add more detail than that.....

Comment: This is oddly unspecific :D

Comment: like the others said before, please put a bit more love into your question, add some code, make it easier for ppl here to help you.

Comment: you need to crop that much part of the image using the co-ordinates returned and save it as an image

Answer (score 1):

Saving the faces will require you to compute the bounding box of the faces from the detection output, then write them to a file. Hint: have a look at OpenCV's documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/objdetect.html) and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/highgui.html).

You can detect more features such as eyes, nose... in just the same way as the faces. However, you need a different trained cascade for each different feature. OpenCV already provides you with a cascade for eyes (and glasses). For eyebrows, nose... you'll likely build your own cascade, for example by following the instructions in [this great blog post](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html).